# Restarting a thread with different inputs

Tags: c#, multithreading

First off - apologies if this or a similar question has been asked before. It feels like it should have been, but I've been unable to find one.

I have a third party assembly with a method I'm calling, this method has parameters taking a list of objects (in concept, not `List<object>`) and returns a result after a potentially long running algorithm.

I call this method on a different thread to preserve UI responsiveness. And it gets called quite regularly and with a different list of values. This means that it's often running when I want to re-run it. The problem I have is that the creation of the new thread is quite naive so it fires off a new one each time - this results in multiple threads running with different input parameters. What I actually want to happen is for any existing threads to die as I'm no longer interested in their output.

I'm not very familiar with multi threading best practises so I would really like some suggestions on the best way to approach this problem.

(I'm using 3.5 so no TPL)

**EDIT**
I cracked out Reflector to see what was going on inside and a lot of the code is marked `protected` so I'm pretty certain I can inherit and wrap the call in a check to quit early as per the answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could treat this as a Producer/Consumer pattern.

Instead of starting a Thread, post (produce) a new Datapacket.

The Consuming Thread should monitor the queue and start on a new packet when it arrives.

Note that stopping the Thread is your main issue here. Don't even look at Thread.Abort(). You need to build that logic into the thread-code.

Comment: Indeed, the stopping is the main problem. What do you mean by "build that logic into the thread-code". I understand how can this can be achieved if I weren't using a third party assembly, but I'm a bit stuck as there's no way to tell the method to stop - only the thread.

Comment: You should have a boolean or likewize indicating new data, "dataPosted" that is set to false in the first part of the thread and then all through the thread, check if it has been set to true again and then discard all working data and return to beginning to fetch new data.

Comment: @David: Evidently the third-party code doesn't contain those checks.  How do you propose to introduce them into a long running function available to you only in compiled binary form?

Comment: Then the only option would be to let the thread run to the end and discard any result from obsolete runs, I do not think there are any other "clean" option.

Comment: @RichK: Though choice, but stopping (Aborting) the Thread is dangerous. If you cannot make the 3rd party method stop then either let it run or you will have to launch them  in a separate AppDomain. You can kill that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't restart a single thread. What you *could* do is maintain a queue of jobs. Then, when executing a job you could check periodically whether there are any newer jobs - if there are, abandon the current one and start the new one. This is easiest when each "job" consists of performing many tasks (e.g. the same task on multiple inputs within the job, or various different steps). In that case, just check before you start each task.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I go about "abandon[ing] the current one"? It's still running in the background sucking up my CPU and various things happen when it's finished that I'm not interested in.

Comment: @RichK: No, you misunderstand me - the code *performing the job* would need to notice that the job was no longer required, and stop working on it. Judging by your other comments, this is third party code, which means you're out of luck. There's no way of *cleanly* and reliably stopping code which isn't designed to be stopped like this.

Comment: Whoa, Skeet overlooked an answer?  I think this means the answer no longer matters because *the world is about to end*.

Answer (score 1):

A couple questions have to be asked about this third-party code:

- Does it write to persistent storage during processing?  i.e. files or to a database
- If it writes to persistent storage, does that affect future runs?  (probably not, as you've been able to run in parallel)

If the answer to both questions is yes, you're in a difficult situation.  It's hard to imagine any way of restoring the persistent storage to a consistent state which wouldn't be more expensive than just letting the algorithm run to completion.  (Although if long-running means more than a couple minutes, doing a VM clone and transferring the data to it might be less work.)

If either question is no, you can abort processing.  But the smallest unit which Windows allows you to cleanly abort is a *process*.  You'll have to spawn a worker process to perform the calculation.  The most straightforward way is to build a TCP service (.NET comes with tools for this -- WCF).  If the third-party code only reads its input data, you can use tools like shared memory to reduce the cost of transferring data to this subprocess.

Comment: That's definitely an option to consider. It's likely to be ugly and involve a fair amount of plumbing code though... as well as having the inefficiency of creating a new process each time. May or may not be appropriate based on the actual situation, but +1 for thinking outside the (process) box.

Comment: No data persistence, so I may look at what you've suggested - but it sounds pretty terrifying. Thanks.